# C# ViewModel object creation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am reading some ViewModel tutorials and I'm trying to implement it in a window that creates a "Station" object. My model station is the following:

```
using System;

namespace Model
{
    public class Station
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public Station(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Station cannot have no name.");
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

How would one create a ViewModel that binds to a WPF form and create a new Station instance and add it to a repository or some list using a facade? My question is particularly about Exceptions and how they're handled with bindings and I'm also asking how to do it without setters because all of the tutorials I've read are using setters.

I don't want to use setters because logically a station is required to have a name and shouldn't be instanciated without a name.

Comment: It perfectly fine to have readonly properties in the view model.As for the design of the viewmodel, you need to tell more about the view functionality. Does it display station details? Or a list of stations with options to create new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would solve this.

Imported namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using ReactiveUI; // nuget package reactiveui
```

Models

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Station
    {
        public Station(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(name));
            }

            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

Services

```
namespace Services
{
    public interface IStationService
    {
        Task CreateAsync(Models.Station model);
        Task UpdateAsync(Models.Station oldModel, Models.Station newModel);
    }
}
```

ViewModels.Base

```
namespace ViewModels.Base
{
    public class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
    {
        public virtual Task InitializeAsync(object parameter)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModels

You can extend this example and "disable" the command if `Name` is null/empty or equals the name in `_originalModel` to prevent exceptions while executing the save command.

Or you can catch the exception in `SaveCommandExecuteAsync`.

The main point is: I only create a new model instance when I want to save it.

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class StationEditViewModel : Base.ViewModelBase
    {
        public StationEditViewModel(Services.IStationService stationService)
        {
            StationService = stationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stationService));
        }

        protected Services.IStationService StationService { get; }

        string _name;
        public string Name { get => _name; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value); }

        public ICommand SaveCommand => ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SaveCommandExecuteAsync);

        private async Task SaveCommandExecuteAsync()
        {
            var oldModel = _originalModel;
            var newModel = await SaveToModelAsync();
            if (oldModel == null)
                await StationService.CreateAsync(newModel);
            else
                await StationService.UpdateAsync(oldModel, newModel);
            await LoadFromModelAsync(newModel);
        }
        public override Task InitializeAsync(object parameter)
        {
            return LoadFromModelAsync(parameter as Models.Station);
        }

        Models.Station _originalModel;
        private Task LoadFromModelAsync(Models.Station model)
        {
            _originalModel = model;
            Name = model?.Name;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task<Models.Station> SaveToModelAsync()
        {
            var model = new Models.Station(Name);
            return Task.FromResult(model);
        }
    }
}
```

A final test in a console app

```
namespace so53567553
{
    using Models;

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var service = new TestStationService();
            var vm = new ViewModels.StationEditViewModel(service);
            vm.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine($"PropertyChanged '{e.PropertyName}'");

            // we will work on a new Station
            Console.WriteLine("* Create Station");

            await vm.InitializeAsync(null);

            vm.Name = "New Station";
            vm.SaveCommand.Execute(null);

            // we will work on an existing Station
            Console.WriteLine("* Edit Station");

            await vm.InitializeAsync(new Station("Paddington"));
            vm.Name = "London";
            vm.SaveCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }

    class TestStationService : Services.IStationService
    {
        public Task CreateAsync(Station model)
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Create Station '{model.Name}'");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task UpdateAsync(Station oldModel, Station newModel)
        {
            if (oldModel == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(oldModel));
            }

            if (newModel == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newModel));
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Update Station from '{oldModel.Name}' to '{newModel.Name}'");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```